# Show value of select option in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-sheets

I have a list with the  tag, the item values ​​are obtained through an online spreadsheet. When selecting an option, the value does not appear in the html in real time. can anybody help me? I'm trying to solve it, but I can't find the error.

[CODEPEN LINK EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/cinthia-danielle/pen/oNYzVzZ)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var sheetURL =
         "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1J0qyxUCCkvcFGZ6EIy9nDOgEuTlpI5ICVG3ZsBd_H-I/1/public/values?alt=json";
       $.getJSON(sheetURL, function(data) {
         var entryData = data.feed.entry;
         console.log(data);
         jQuery.each(entryData, function() {
           $("#divTax").append(
      
      '<option  hidden="hidden" selected="selected"  value="0">CHOISE</option><option value="' + this.gsx$values.$t +  '">' + this.gsx$names.$t + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$' + this.gsx$values.$t + '</option>'
     
           );
         });
       });
      });

  
var totalWithTax = $('#divTax :selected').val();
  $('.total').html(totalWithTax);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select style="width: 80%;" id="divTax"></select>
  <br>  
Total:<div class="total"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing an event listener like  $('select').on('change', function () or $('#divTax').on('change', function ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to put the code that displays the selection in an event listener.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sheetURL =
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1J0qyxUCCkvcFGZ6EIy9nDOgEuTlpI5ICVG3ZsBd_H-I/1/public/values?alt=json";
  $.getJSON(sheetURL, function(data) {
    var entryData = data.feed.entry;
    jQuery.each(entryData, function() {
      $("#divTax").append(

        '<option  hidden="hidden" selected="selected"  value="0">CHOISE</option><option value="' + this.gsx$values.$t + '">' + this.gsx$names.$t + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$' + this.gsx$values.$t + '</option>'

      );
    });
  });
  
  $("#divTax").change(function() {
    var totalWithTax = $(this).val();
    $('.total').text(totalWithTax);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select style="width: 80%;" id="divTax"></select>
<br> Total:
<div class="total"></div>
```